# Pesquisa em 3 tabelas

Tags: tabela-banco-de-dados, relacionamento

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE alunos (
 id_aluno int not null,
 nome VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id_aluno)
)

CREATE TABLE aulas (
id_aula int not null,
nome VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(id_aula)
)

CREATE TABLE matriculas (
id_aluno int not null,
id_aula int not null,
FOREIGN KEY (id_aluno) REFERENCES alunos(id_aluno),
FOREIGN key (id_aula) REFERENCES aulas(id_aula)
)
```

e com os seguintes dados:

```
INSERT INTO alunos (id_aluno, nome) VALUES ('10', 'JOÃO');
INSERT INTO alunos (id_aluno, nome) VALUES  ('11', 'MARIA');

insert into aulas (id_aula, nome) VALUES ('1', 'Português');
insert into aulas (id_aula, nome) VALUES ('2', 'Matematica');
insert into aulas (id_aula, nome) VALUES ('3', 'História');
insert into aulas (id_aula, nome) VALUES ('4', 'Ciência');

insert into matriculas (id_aluno, id_aula) VALUES ('10','1');
insert into matriculas (id_aluno, id_aula) VALUES ('10','2');
insert into matriculas (id_aluno, id_aula) VALUES ('11','3');
insert into matriculas (id_aluno, id_aula) VALUES ('11','4');
insert into matriculas (id_aluno, id_aula) VALUES ('11','2');
```

Logo, João tem as aulas Português e Matematica e Maria Matematica, Historia e Ciência.

Perguntas:

1- Como poderia fazer uma query para pegar o nome da aula em que joão e maria   estão cadastrados? (no caso Matematica) Ou suponha que eu tenha 10 alunos cadastrados e eles tem pelo menos uma aula em comum entre si e eu queira saber qual é.

2-Essa seria ao contrario eu queria saber quais alunos estão cadastrado em uma determinada aula. Português por exemplo.

Comment: Fundamental entender: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70

Comment: Poderia mostrar uma resposta pronta, mas acredito que, do ponto de vista de aprendizado, seria muito bom se você entender os conceitos de *joins* entre tabelas usando linguagem *SQL*. Acrescentando ao que o @Bacco mencionou, sugiro essa leitura, muito ilustrativa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join